# Tweet not showing variable as string?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, clipboard, pasteboard

I've created a small app to get the clipboard on IOS using swift, but when I try to tweet the variable, it's not showing up as a string, it shows up as

`<UILabel: 0x146db1a30; frame = (78.6667 229; 257 147); text = 'I'm on my way right now'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x146db1fd0>>`

instead of

`\(clipText)`

The code I have to get the clipboard contents is

```
let pasteboardString:String? = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string
clipText.text = pasteboardString`
```

When I go to post the tweet using this code

```
let tweetController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
tweetController.setInitialText("Here's what was on my clipboard:(clipText)")
```

I get the text from the top instead.

[Image of the code I get instead of (clipText)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2iiP.jpg)

Comment: You want `clipText.text`, not `clipText`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let pasteboardString:String? = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().absolutString
clipText.text = "\(pasteboardString)"
```

But you do not need to post UILabel The message is correct because you are trying to post UILabel object. instead of this try to post only string or UILabel's text

instead of `"\(clipText)"` use `"\(clipText.text)"`

Comment: Why `"\(pasteboardString)"` and not just `pasteboardString`?

Comment: first method gives compilator some value which will be presented as string so if your pasteboardString some how will be type of int it will return always String format in "\()"

Comment: Solved by doing `var pasteboardString:String! = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string` instead. Thanks for the help and suggestions!